# How to get a Previous request value

Tags: c#

I am calling a **WebService** and getting a double value from below code.

```
double exchangevalue = exchangerate.ConversionRate(CurrencyExchange.Currency.INR,     CurrencyExchange.Currency.AED);
```

Once I am connected to Internet i am getting the double value from `webService` and doing my stuff.

Suppose I am not connected to Internet,so I will not get value from the previous line of code,because it can't call the `webservice`. So I want to get the value from previous request.
So how to store the previous request value so that I can use that value when my Internet connection is off.

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well,you mentioned that you want to use '`Previous value`',than when you get value from web service,store it somewhere at client. There are so many options for storing it.

When you don't have **internet connection**,get the stored value and perform the operation.When you get the internet connection,obtain value again and update it by replacing the already stored one.

Regards..